# Inline google stylsheet link to a div

Tags: html, css, django

I was just thinking of giving the users the feature to chose fonts from google and take the url, to use it in the template.

**Is it possible to place a stylesheet link directly to a div?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Eg:

```
<div id="post" href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Share+Tech' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add a separate stylesheet to an element.

You can use inline styling via the `style` attribute.

```
<div style="font-family:arial;"></div>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2

Better yet, dynamically add a specific class based on the user input and style it in the global stylesheet.